# How to deploy a website in jsp

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a website in JSP developed with Java EE technologies like Struts and Hibernate using Netbeans and Glassfish.

I want to deploy it on web. How do I do it? I also need about 10 MySql Databases and 3 email accounts on hosting.
Which server is suitable for it, Windows or Linux?
I am also not finding anywhere written JSP on any of the hosting provider websites. What is the senario about JSP?

Also list some most secure and best web hosting provider which respects customers privacy and security. I am from Delhi, India.

Comment: Any more reviews or suggestions is greatly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP may be hosted on both Linux and Windows server.

However, most of the popular and low-cost hosts do not support JSP as Java is resource-intensive.

I would recommend [Network Solutions](http://www.networksolutions.com).

You may want to check with the hosts directly regarding support for JSP.

Alternatively, you may check out [Hosting Review](http://www.hosting-review.com/) for great deals. However, for those hosts who do not state whether they support JSP, do contact their live support to confirm.

Be sure to read the reviews on the hosts carefully before making a decision and do not just go for the cheapest one.

An additional tip would be to deactivate auto-renewal and remove your credit card information totally from the host after payment as some rogue hosts may impose hidden fees and automatically charge them to your card according to your card details.